# FileSystemWatcher locks file and won't release it

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm facing an issue now for a while. Lot of searching, didn't find a solution :(

I have a little program which should watch for a new file, and open it. When the `OnFileCreated` event triggers, this error shows up:

```
IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process
```

The file is locked by my program itself.

What can be the problem? This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        string dirPath = @"B:\watchdir";
        watcher.Path = dirPath;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileCreated);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: From experience it is not the FileSystemWatcher that causes this problem, but the most likely culprit is anti-virus software that sees the new file and starts to scan it.

Comment: On top of @sgmoore's comment, What is creating/putting the file at your location? That could possibly be what is holding the lock, or not finished copying/creating the file. OnCreated is called as soon as the file appears, weather its finished or not. To quote the docs: "The `OnCreated` event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged events."

Comment: I see, no anti virus enabled at this machine. When I try to delete the new file created there (btw I copy the file there with explorer.exe) it says that I cannot delete this file since my program locked it (I'm also deleting from explorer).

Comment: I think everyone is correct.  You are responding to the event too quickly while the file is still being written to for the first time but you are trying to immediately open it.  I used FileSystemWatcher years ago and ultimately implemented a queue that the Created event filled.  A separate thread processed the files in the queue when it was safe to open them.  And if you open the file, close it!

Comment: To find out what has the file open (and possibly locked) see https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileShare.ReadWrite` instead of `FileShare.Read`

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(e.FullPath, 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read, 
                                   FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
        }
```

Comment: This really depends on what the author of the question is trying to do, if they only want to read the file then they should stick to `FileShare.Read` giving more persmissions than necessaryis not always the answer

Comment: Mark Davies is right, and it also does not matter in this case. I tried both, nothing changed, still locked.